# How to update column value when system datetime reach datetime saved in other column? in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, ssms-2012

I have one table with 2 columns. One is called "houranddate" and is datetime type and the other is called "status" and is int type.
I want the value in "status" column to be updated to "1" when the the server datetime reaches the same datetime value saved int the column "houranddate".

Is there any chance that I set this in sql server MS or the only way is to use some web service?

Comment: You can schedule a Job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use a computed column:

```
alter table t
    add new_status as (case when datetimecol >= getdate() then 1 else status end);
```

(Or, what I would do in this case is name the existing column something like `_status` and the new one `status`.)

If `status` is 0 before that time, then drop the existing `status` column and instead:

```
alter table t
    add status as (case when datetimecol >= getdate() then 1 else 0 end);
```

The computed column is calculated when it is used.  So, it is always up-to-date, without the use of jobs or `update`.

Comment: Any reason for the anonymous downvote?  This seems like the simplest solution for what the OP wants to accomplish.

Comment: The only reason I can imagine someone down-voted is because you can't index this column, but they should have said something. I had the same idea before I deleted my answer, my syntax was for `create table` and yours seemed more appropriate. Have my upvote +1

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That makes sense. Solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an SQL Agent scheduled job to do this, but I would not recommend it. Better to handle such things in the select statement:

```
SELECT houranddate, case when houranddate > getdate() then 1 else [status] end as [status]
FROM tablename
```

Comment: The problem with relying on a query is that another person/application that browses the table will only see the old status.  I think the OP wants to be sure that all access to the table see the same data.